# Sign .NET MAUI app with Google generated keys

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, maui

I upgraded my keys on Google Play console and now when I try to upload my Android package, I get an error stating the SHA fingerprints don't match.

What do I need to do here? Do I need to create a new keystore containing the new SHA values?

Answer (score 0):

When you update your key in Google Play, the fingerprints of your certificate will also change. You can try to update your app to recognize the old and new app signing key certificates or sign your app with your new key, after which you try uploading your Android package again.

For more details, please refer to:

[Publish a .NET MAUI app for Android | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0)

[Sign your app | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: My specific question is what exactly I need to do to incorporate the new upload key assigned by Google. I think I need to create a new keystore but how will the new upload key assigned by Google be used in that keystore?

Comment: You can try to download your upload certificate in Google Play, and then use the command: `keytool.exe -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore <keystorefile>` to add the certificate to your keystore.